# Are questions about film themes on topic at English.SE?

Tags: discussion, on-topic-off-topic

A large part of our English class is identification and analysis of film themes, and using these film themes in exams to answer questions ([a](http://www.nzqa.govt.nz/nqfdocs/ncea-resource/exams/2013/91473-exm-2013.pdf) [few](http://www.nzqa.govt.nz/nqfdocs/ncea-resource/exams/2013/91099-exm-2013.pdf) [examples](http://www.nzqa.govt.nz/nqfdocs/ncea-resource/exams/2013/90850-exm-2013.pdf) across different levels).

Are questions about the **identification** and **analysis** of film themes on-topic at English.SE, or would they be better suited for [Movies.SE](https://movies.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: Such questions are not on topic on EL&U, but I can't comment on whether they're on topic at Movies.SE (I didn't even know that stack existed til now!).

Comment: Would the themes be the same in another language?

Comment: @Mitch - I suppose so...

Comment: Aside from the rare question about a line that is unusual or doesn't make sense in everyday English, these are largely OT here. Discussion and analysis is definitely OT. :( I hope you find your site (and if you would be kind enough to let me know when you do, I'd be very grateful.)

Comment: @medica - Is "OT" _on-topic_, or _off-topic_? (From the context of your remark, I can tell what you mean, but I thought I'd mention the potential for ambiguity with that shorthand.)

Comment: Sorry, OT = off topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to ask on Movies. As it says on their [help page](https://movies.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic):

> ### What topics can I ask about here?
>
> If your question generally covers …
>
> - Analysis of content or **theme of all forms of Movies** and TV series

That said, I'd be careful about copying questions from your class verbatim into a question, and seeing what others think. That kind of question smacks of "homework help," which is generally regarded with disdain across the Stack Exchange.

However, if you take a cut at answering the question, and you're asking for help on some smaller part of it, I think that might be your best place to start.